# os.walk() is not printing anything when providing the current directory path as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is not generating any output when I provide the current directory path as a string to `os.walk()` method but when I provide `os.getcwd()` as an argument to the `os.walk()` method, it prints the desired output.

```
import os
dir='/Users/shiva/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39'
for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(dir):
    print(f'dirpath={dirpath}\ndirnames={dirnames}\nfilenames={filenames}')
```

Comment: So, presumably `dir != os.getcwd()` and `len(os.listdir(dir)) == 0`?

Comment: @ekhumoro I have tried running the same code with different path names as well but still there is no output but just when  I change the directories (to traverse through the desired directory) and provide os.getcwd() as an argument to the os.walk() method, it works fine.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't use `dir` as a variable name since it's a python builtin function. 2) Are you sure the path is right? it looks like a partial path in Windows C drive.

Comment: @GENIUSNETWORK The path names you are using very likely don't exist. Note that, by default, `os.walk` *does not report errors*. What output do you see when executing this: `list(os.walk(dir, onerror=print))`?

Comment: So then do `print(repr(os.getcwd()))` and copy-paste the result in your code, e.g. `dir = <the output of the print statement>`. Does that work? If so, can you figure out the difference between that directory and the directory you initially had in your code?

Answer (score -2):

#### Use Raw String for Path

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print(f'dirpath={dirpath}\ndirnames={dirnames}\nfilenames={filenames}')
```

Comment: Why do you think this would solve the problem? Raw strings are just one possible way to provide string literals. Escaping the backslashes is also possible. And using forward slashes, as OP did, works just fine as well, even in Windows. I fail to see how this answers the question.